# Group editing privilege

Tags: bugzilla

I'm new of administering Bugzilla, it is possible to set priviledges so every member of a group can edit bugs assigned to a member of the same group?

For example, if I am member of `groupA` and have an assigned bug another member of `GroupA`, can that member take this bug and edit some values?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have edit bug permission enabled, then you can edit bugs assigned to a member of the same group.

if you didn't set the edit bug permission, set through the following  :

- click employee link
- type your username and search
- click on your username and put tick mark on the edit bugs

if you are admin, click the first set of check boxes to get the admin privilege.
else use the second set of check boxes

Answer (score 0):

If the user you assigned to the bug is a member of your group and have the editbugs permission , he will have the ability to change ALL bug fields.

I think you can denied him from the editbugs permission , but then what will be the point of assigned him to the bug , if he cant update his progress and write comments...